# Group matching timestamps into buckets and summarize count

Tags: kql

I'm looking for a query that would return 3 numbers for each unique timestamp from the table below. For each timestamp, the count of entries below some fixed threshold, the count above another threshold, and the count between.

[database entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIXYf.png)

The result would look like this

[what I want to return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/borUm.png)

I think I can get at least one of the three counts with the following, but I can't figure out how to get all three to return:

```
| where TimestampId > ago(4h) 
| project aboveCount = Value > 75
| summarize count()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please replace the image with text, e.g., CSV

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let t = materialize(range Id from 1 to 100 step 1 | extend Timestamp = bin(ago(1h * rand()), 15m), Value = rand(100));
// Solution starts here.
let low_threshold = 25;
let high_threshold = 75;
t
| summarize aboveCount      = countif(Value > high_threshold)
           ,underCount      = countif(Value < low_threshold)
           ,betweenCount    = countif(Value between (low_threshold .. high_threshold))
            by Timestamp
```

| Timestamp | aboveCount | underCount | betweenCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-20T14:00:00Z | 6 | 6 | 9 |
| 2023-01-20T14:15:00Z | 8 | 6 | 12 |
| 2023-01-20T14:30:00Z | 4 | 4 | 11 |
| 2023-01-20T14:45:00Z | 6 | 9 | 10 |
| 2023-01-20T15:00:00Z | 1 | 0 | 8 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32QPU/DMBCG90j5D%20/ooCppkCqGUhYmFhYQK3LIJbbkj8i%20UED98bhpRJUM3GDp/Po5P3ZV4UXawRBayRI9OQqStXclnj1jkIHhO7AiRG/GKckzQwzGAVYyBS2N/iERpOsJTy264C1qsEe93SIyDak7gb6YXItXbSlyujLhjXZC9l7UCjdIfCuKYoN6Z9P6Js1I6cy0nQYVxT7PqmQ7W6TByS1CUaDZyPjjO6tAUXnTJvR2t78ESvdqkdydE86zE%20JorQzJH7Lxn/ToR8eY6oCPc6M7cVF5WI0p8gzX2oyupfAPfr/UW9EN8ZHI/fFres4hlm8sy7XUci6a7%20uH/wLwJHh86wEAAA==)